# '=' should initialize either all enum members or only the first;

Tags: c++, enums, lint

I am trying to build my code with following enum values :

```
typedef enum {           
    YUV_420P=0,    
    YUV_422P,         
    RGB_P,       
    BAYER_P,      
    YUV_422IBE,     
    YUV_444IBE,       
    A_1BIT,                  
    YUV_420SP,          
    COMPLEX_8BIT,             
    COMPLEX_16BIT,            
    COMPLEX_32BIT,        
    COMPLEX_U8BIT,           
    COMPLEX_U16BIT,            
    COMPLEX_U32BIT,                                   
    ALPHA_TYPE=0x8000                  
} Format;
```

But during building I am getting the below linting warning ..

```
sample.h: Note 960: Violates MISRA 2004 Required Rule 9.3, '=' should initialize either all enum members or only the first; enumerator: 'ALPHA_TYPE' ..
```

I don't want to change value of ALPHA_TYPE and I want to put the ALPHA_TYPE in this enum only. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you need compliance with MISRA coding standard? If not, you can ignore this.

Comment: You are not invoking the dreaded undefined behavior, and it's common to specify the integral value of the first element with the understanding the rest will sequentially follow. Unless the warning fits your requirements ignore it.

Comment: That's a rather strange requirement even for an aggressive static analysis. Perhaps MISRA doesn't understand what enumerators are.

Comment: @Lightness MISRA imposes a lot of nonsensical rules in the name of *safety*; having to write `if(var != 0) {}` instead of `if(var) {}` unless `var` is `_Bool`, is one that comes to mind. Ashwin: You have bigger problems with that code than the MISRA warning, `1BIT` is not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 4):

Your code already does what you want. You just need to suppress this particular warning.

On the other hand, if you absolutely do need to adhere to this MISRA 2004 rule 9.3, then you will need to change your code and find a different solution. But you cannot have it both ways.

Comment: Ignoring a warning is no good (In the end you will get many and miss serious warnings) - Fix the code or silence the warning (If you consider it useless in general)

Comment: @DieterLücking You are suggesting exactly the same as I am! Silence the warning. I'm certainly not proposing that all compiler warnings are just ignored. Just this non-compiler warning in this context, once the dev has decided that it can be silenced.

Comment: @DieterLücking's advice is smart. If you just "ignore" warnings, then eventually the list grows so large that you miss important ones.  Silence that specific one, if possible, or if you don't need MISRA, silence the MISRA warnings.  ...or spit warnings to a logfile and grep it to automatically filter out unwanted, retaining useful.

Comment: @DavidO I agree. I am not suggesting otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

If values of other enums does not matter, you can do this

```
typedef enum {           
    ALPHA_TYPE=0x8000,                  
    YUV_420P,    
    YUV_422P,         
    RGB_P,       
    BAYER_P,      
    YUV_422IBE,     
    YUV_444IBE,       
    1BIT,                  
    YUV_420SP,          
    COMPLEX_8BIT,             
    COMPLEX_16BIT,            
    COMPLEX_32BIT,        
    COMPLEX_U8BIT,           
    COMPLEX_U16BIT,            
    COMPLEX_U32BIT                                   
} Format;
```

**Or**

Define all your enum values like this (this avoid one of your enum value to change, if you add a new one)

```
  typedef enum {                           
    YUV_420P=0,    
    YUV_422P=1,         
    RGB_P=2,       
    BAYER_P=3,      
    YUV_422IBE=4,     
    YUV_444IBE=5,       
    1BIT=6,                  
    YUV_420SP=7,          
    COMPLEX_8BIT=8,             
    COMPLEX_16BIT=9,            
    COMPLEX_32BIT=10,        
    COMPLEX_U8BIT=11,           
    COMPLEX_U16BIT=12,            
    COMPLEX_U32BIT=13,
    ALPHA_TYPE=0x8000                                   
} Format;
```

Comment: That very much changes the values of the other names, e.g. making a range check more difficult.

Comment: And since you do not know how the enum is being used in the rest of the code, you don't know if the values are significant or not.

Comment: As misra 9.3 rule statement is like :9.3 (req) In an enumerator list, the “=” construct shall not be used to
explicitly initialise members other than the first, unless all items
are explicitly initialised.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly not a C++ requirement.

> `[C++11: 7.2/2]:` An *enumerator-definition* with `=` gives the associated enumerator the value indicated by the *constant-expression*. If the first enumerator has no initializer, the value of the corresponding constant is zero. An *enumerator-definition* without an initializer gives the enumerator the value obtained by increasing the value of the previous enumerator
>   by one.

The grammar above it allows multiple enumerators to have an initializer.

If you are allowed, perhaps you can turn off checks for compliance with this "MISRA 2004" rule. You could also simply ignore it since it appears to be a mere `Note`. Personally I would be a bit annoyed to have that popping up all the time, but perhaps that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Since the first enum value is 0, and since it is that also by default, simply use the default.</del> <sub><sup>← I misread the warning, this point is not a solution.</sup></sub>

And/or, turn off the MISRA rule checking.

And/or, ignore the specific note. Apparently you can do that via an [`+esym`](http://www.gimpel.com/html/lintdev.htm) option. Or maybe `-esym`, just try out things and check the documentation.

Comment: -1: How will removing the initialiser for the first enumerator solve this problem? The initialiser on the last one will still trigger this condition.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: thanks, I misread the note/warning, reading "or only the first" (which doesn't make sense to me) as "or only the last" (which is very meaningful, it's a common idiom to use the last one as a max value, initialized with the next-to-last)

Comment: Indeed. It's a slightly strange thing for even an aggressive static analyser to moan about.